# Why does csv.DictReader skip empty lines?

Tags: python, file, csv

It seems that `csv.DictReader` skips empty lines, even when `restval` is set. Using the following, empty lines in the input file are skipped:

```
import csv
CSV_FIELDS = ("field1", "field2", "field3")
for row in csv.DictReader(open("f"), fieldnames=CSV_FIELDS, restval=""):
    if not row or not row[CSV_FIELDS[0]]:
        sys.exit("never reached, why?")
```

Where file `f` is:

```
1,2,3


a,b,c
```

Comment: What is the desired behaviour?

Comment: If you have an empty line with only 2 commas, i.e. `,,` then `"never reached, why?"` would be printed. Is that what you want?

Comment: For what it’s worth, this is the behaviour I would expect, and I’d even claim that this should be obvious: an empty line is not an empty record, it’s the *absence* of a record.

Comment: @mdurant: That when there are less fields than should be, missing ones be `restval`. At least that would be my interpretation of the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

Comment: @BhargavRao: yes for sure, but I want to know empty lines are there.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: it may be what you expect but it is not my interpretation of the doc. In my scenario I want to know when lines are empty, or said differently when all values are missing.

Comment: At those upping mdurant's comment: I am asking a question, not a "what is the desired behaviour question", gee

Comment: What difference does it make? It's the way it is.

Comment: @isonix Okay, fair point. But the documentation of `restval` is unrelated to empty lines, it’s about *missing fields* at the end of a line.

Comment: @martineau I was hoping I missed some obscure parameter with DictReader or some sort of workaround

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Inside the csv.DictReader class](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ac176a69d188/Lib/csv.py#l116):

```
    # unlike the basic reader, we prefer not to return blanks,
    # because we will typically wind up with a dict full of None
    # values
    while row == []:
        row = self.reader.next()
```

So empty rows are skipped.
If you don't want to skip empty lines, you could instead use `csv.reader`.

Another option is to subclass `csv.DictReader`:

```
import csv
CSV_FIELDS = ("field1", "field2", "field3")

class MyDictReader(csv.DictReader):
    def next(self):
        if self.line_num == 0:
            # Used only for its side effect.
            self.fieldnames
        row = self.reader.next()
        self.line_num = self.reader.line_num

        d = dict(zip(self.fieldnames, row))
        lf = len(self.fieldnames)
        lr = len(row)
        if lf < lr:
            d[self.restkey] = row[lf:]
        elif lf > lr:
            for key in self.fieldnames[lr:]:
                d[key] = self.restval
        return d

for row in MyDictReader(open("f", 'rb'), fieldnames=CSV_FIELDS, restval=""):
    print(row)
```

yields

```
{'field2': '2', 'field3': '3', 'field1': '1'}
{'field2': '', 'field3': '', 'field1': ''}
{'field2': '', 'field3': '', 'field1': ''}
{'field2': 'b', 'field3': 'c', 'field1': 'a'}
```

Comment: ah great... differing behavior from reader to DictReader, thanks for finding that

Comment: woa that is clean and works out of the box with 2.6, many thanks! (plus you didn't mind just answering my question which I find cool)

Answer (score 3):

Unutbu already pointed out to the reason why this is happening, anyways a quick fix will be replace empty lines with `','` before passing them to `DictReader` then `restval` will take care of the rest of the things.

```
CSV_FIELDS = ("field1", "field2", "field3")

with open('test.csv') as f:
    lines = (',' if line.isspace() else line for line in f)
    for row in csv.DictReader(lines, fieldnames=CSV_FIELDS, restval=""):
        print row

#output
{'field2': '2', 'field3': '3', 'field1': '1'}
{'field2': '', 'field3': '', 'field1': ''}
{'field2': '', 'field3': '', 'field1': ''}
{'field2': 'b', 'field3': 'c', 'field1': 'a'}
```

**Update:**

In case of multi-line empty values the above code won't do it, in that case you can use `csv.reader` like this:

```
RESTVAL = ''

with open('test.csv') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f, quotechar='"'):
        if not row:
            # Don't use `dict.fromkeys` if RESTVAL is a mutable object
            # {k: RESTVAL for k in CSV_FIELDS}
            print dict.fromkeys(CSV_FIELDS, RESTVAL)
        else:
            print {k: v if v else RESTVAL for k, v in zip(CSV_FIELDS, row)}
```

If file contains:

```
1,2,"


4"


a,b,c
```

then the output will be:

```
{'field2': '2', 'field3': '\n\n\n4', 'field1': '1'}
{'field2': '', 'field3': '', 'field1': ''}
{'field2': '', 'field3': '', 'field1': ''}
{'field2': 'b', 'field3': 'c', 'field1': 'a'}
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I have mutliple line values in my real life CSV file.

Comment: @isonix What do you mean by multiple line values?

Comment: An empty line could be part of a single value rather than be just an "all values missing csv empty line".

Comment: looks cool I am trying it now thanks! why the `quotechar='"'`?

Comment: @isonix My sample input is using `"` for multiple line data.

Answer (score 0):

This is your file :

```
1,2,3
,,
,,
a,b,c
```

I add coma and now he takes two empty lines `{'field2': '', 'field3': '', 'field1': ''}`
For `restval` argument, it just say if you have set fields but one is missing, the other values go to this value.

So you set three fields and there are three values each time. But we talk about 'columns' right here and not lines.

Your lines were empty so he skipped it, unless you specify with comas he needs to take empty values, for dictreader.